# Proof by Contradiction that n is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone help with this proof?

$$P(n): \forall n \in Z, n^2 + 5 $$ is odd implies that n is even.

I honestly don't even know where to start. I do know that $n=2k$ is even, and $n=2k + 1$ is odd, but I don't know how to use them

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you want to do it by contradiction? Proving the contrapositive (if $n$ is odd then $n^2+5$ is even) would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try expanding the bracket? if $n = 2k$ and $n = 2k+1$ what is $n^2$ in terms of $k$?

Comment: It would be: $n^2 = 4k$ and $4k^2+2$

Comment: Try again? as they are both not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is odd. Can you get a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is by recognizing that all perfect squares are congruent to $0$ or $1$ (mod $4$).